# Formulating MatLab Deep Neural Network without Images

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, regression

I am trying to use MatLab to generate a neural network capable of regression.  Essentially, I would like to map 36 inputs to 24 outputs.  (Eventually I would like to transition the network to an RNN or LSTM architecture, but not yet.)

Sadly, I can only find documentation for image inputs!  MatLab documentation recommends setting up the layers as such:

```
layers = [
    imageInputLayer([28 28 1])

    convolution2dLayer(3,8,'Padding','same')
    batchNormalizationLayer
    reluLayer

    averagePooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)

    convolution2dLayer(3,16,'Padding','same')
    batchNormalizationLayer
    reluLayer

    averagePooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)

    convolution2dLayer(3,32,'Padding','same')
    batchNormalizationLayer
    reluLayer

    convolution2dLayer(3,32,'Padding','same')
    batchNormalizationLayer
    reluLayer

    dropoutLayer(0.2)
    fullyConnectedLayer(1)
    regressionLayer];
```

How do I set up the network to simply accept 36 floating point inputs?  I have a 900000 row by 36 column matrix of training data (and corresponding 900000x24 for ground truth) I would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if you have 900000 samples of 36 rows, you have already a flat array as input, so I don't think that the convolutional neural network would be better than a shallow (https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html) or a regression (https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/generalized-regression-neural-networks.html).
Anyway, you should change the imageInputLayer to [1 36 1] as you have only one row, and provide a set of targets for the fitting.

Comment: Exactly, I do not want to use a convolutional network.  However I cannot find documentation for building a simple feedforward net.

Comment: The code you posted is used for CNNs, try looking at this https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html, there is a user-interface toolbox with sample data, but you can load yours